# Chrome Vimeo Iframe autoplay not working anymore

Tags: google-chrome, iframe, vimeo, autoplay

since some days my vimeo iframe will not autoplay anymore. I know the chrome update, which will block autoplay videos with sound. Is the block already active?

The Vimeo Example code doesn't work:

```
<iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/12345?autoplay=1&loop=1&autopause=0" width="500" height="281" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

But netflix.com and vimeo itself has an autoplay video on the homepage, which works.

EDIT: Chrome version 66.0.3359.139 macOS High Sierra 10.13.4

Does anyone have an idea or answer?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a link to a specific video and/or a page where the video is embedded and not autoplaying? I did a quick check on the Vimeo Embed Playground and autoplay works as expected with Chrome 66 on Windows 10: https://player.vimeo.com/embed?videos=76979871|w:640|h:360|a:1|m:0

Comment: i'm sorry it's local project, but you are the right, the playground works. I think it work, because you have an user interaction with the click. If i copy the embed code into a local html file it will not autoplay

Answer (score 9, accepted):

yes, according to their documentation it is.

https://help.vimeo.com/hc/en-us/articles/115004485728-Autoplaying-and-looping-embedded-videos

**EDIT:**

Advance browsers like FireFox, Chrome and Safari are now blocking video autoplay by default.

**CHROME Auto-Play Policy:**

> https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes

The Media Engagement Index, or MEI for short, a way of Chrome is to allow AutoPlay audio on your page to be based on your previous interactions with this webpage as a user. You can see what this looks like by going to

> chrome://media-engagement/

MEI is calculated per user profile, and is persisted to incognito mode.

[image: media engagement]

**WEBKIT/SAFARI Auto-Play Policy:**

> https://webkit.org/blog/7734/auto-play-policy-changes-for-macos/

**FIREFOX Auto-Play Improvements:**

> https://www.ghacks.net/2018/09/21/firefox-improved-autoplay-blocking/

**NOTE:**
 Don’t assume a media element will play, and don’t show the pause button from the start. Look at the Promise returned by the play function on HTMLMediaElement to see if it was rejected:

```
var promise = document.querySelector('video').play();

if (promise !== undefined) {
    promise.catch(error => {
        // Auto-play was prevented
        // Show a UI element to let the user manually start playback
    }).then(() => {
        // Auto-play started
    });
}
```

Comment: @Manshoor-Ahmad The link is broken

Comment: @ManshoorAhmad, Thanks I am seeing the link work now as well. It must have just been a glitch on Vimeo's side for a short period of time.

That is a good example though of why it is important to include details in the answer and not just a link.

Comment: Executing `document.querySelector('video').play()` seems more like programmatic play than autoplay. How would one handle the promise without a `play()` command?

Answer (score 65):

Annotating the `<iframe>` with an `allow` attribute worked for me:

```
<iframe ... allow="autoplay; fullscreen"></iframe>
```

It's called "Iframe delegation" and is described here: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes.

Comment: why is this at the bottom of the page? almost missed it.

Comment: This worked for me - Dec 2018 - to get around the autoplay issue in Chrome. It played with sounds when I added allow="autoplay; fullscreen" to the iframe tag.

Comment: Feb '20, worked for me. Make sure you keep your `?autoplay=1` parameter in after the URL. For example I have `<iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/000000000?autoplay=1&loop=1&autopause=0" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay"></iframe>`
https://vimeo.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/115004485728-Autoplaying-and-looping-embedded-videos
Though `autopause=0` does not seem to work: the video still pauses when I click out of the tab

Comment: `autopause=0` actually seems to disable pausing if you start playing a 2nd video on the same page (as it says in the URL I previously provided: https://vimeo.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/115004485728-Autoplaying-and-looping-embedded-videos ), which I also want

Comment: June 2020, worked for me. I was dynamically generating the iframe in an overlay when the user clicked a "view our video" button (i.e. the user has engaged and wants to view)

Answer (score 38):

You need to add `&muted=1` to the iFrame src path and you need to add the attribute `allow="autoplay"` to the iFrame. Now the Vimeo video starts automatically again in Chrome.

Comment: thanks bro, this  soluition is the beter!

Answer (score 5):

Autoplay + Mute + Start at time x sec  =

```html
<div>
    <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/342787403?&autoplay=1&loop=1&title=0&byline=0&portrait=0&muted=1&#t=235s" style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%;" width="1400" height="900" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen>
    </iframe>
</div>
```

#t parameter must be the last one.

Comment: I tried your code but it doesn't work. I am using Youtube video links.

Comment: that's because the iframe is missing the allow="autoplay" attribute

Answer (score 4):

Now the autoplay video just works if the audio is muted, you need to add the muted parameter into your api or iframe code &muted=1, you can change your browser preferences to allow autoplay unmuted videos: 
chrome://flags/#autoplay-policy
Change the default option to "No user gesture is required"

If the user clicks the video you can unmuted it!!

Answer (score 4):

muted parameter fixed my issue:

```
<iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/x?background=1&autoplay=1&loop=1&byline=0&title=0&muted=1" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen allow="autoplay; fullscreen"></iframe>
```

Comment: Shouldn't the [query string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) start with a question mark?

Comment: muted parameters also worked for me

Answer (score 3):

If you are paid member and want to use video as a background, this is probably what you need:

> **?background=1**: This parameter automatically disables all elements in the player (play bar, buttons, etc), autoplays, loops, and mutes your video on load. Please note: the background parameter is only supported for videos hosted by paid members. Learn more here.

Or, if you are not:

> **?muted=1** This parameter will automatically mute your video on load. Once your video plays, viewers can manually un-mute by clicking on the volume bar within the player.

BUT, I still can't make it work on the phone.